# Form is not working in outlook. can we create forms in email templates that will work in all mailing platforms like gmail, yahoo, outlook etc

Tags: html, email, outlook

I want to create an email template which has a form but its not functional on outlook desktop and other outlook mails.

Is there a way to achieve it if not then can we check which email (eg: gmail, outlook, etc) it is and then show different views.
Basically show a different section for gmail and different for outlook.com?

In my case I have added a get form in html email template and it takes users name an email and routes it to a url. Its working as it should on yahoo and gmail but it routes me to a blank page on outlook when I press submit button of the form.

I tried using if else comments mentioned on some sites:
https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-interactive-forms-in-email/

Here's my code:
"

```
<form action="https://stable.katang.io/gallery/people-society/the-shame-of-new-york-state/6268ed0ee0c44ef681951af26931e71e/5ae900ad9a9c474e800d6e615d797037?fname=Pranali&email=frz.shkh@gmail.com" method="get" target="_blank"> 
  Full Name <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" id="name" name="fname" required /> <br>
  Email Address <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" id="email" name="email" required /> <br>
  <!-- form -->
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>"
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Outlook prevent scripts or forms from running in the message bodies for security reasons. The fact is that Microsoft Office Outlook uses the HTML parsing and rendering engine from Microsoft Office Word to display HTML message bodies. And the such elements like `input`, `form` and etc. are not supported by the rendering engine. You can read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles:

- [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338200(v=office.12))